# Removing a column based on column key in Antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a Table where I can dynamically add columns by clicking a button. Each column header cell can be named by user dynamically.

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    components={{
      header: {
        cell: () => (
          <EditableCell
            handleRemoveColumn={handleRemoveColumn}
          />
        ),
        row: EditableRow,
      },
    }}
    dataSource={datasource}
    tableLayout="fixed"
    style={{ flex: "auto", maxWidth: "96.3%" }}
    scroll={{ x: "auto" }}
    bordered
    pagination={false}
  />
```

The EditableCell is as follow:

```
function EditableCell({ handleRemoveColumn, columnKey }: TChildProp) {
  return (
    <th style={{ padding: "0px 6px 0px 0px" }}>
      <Form.Item style={{ margin: "4px" }}>
        <Space.Compact block={true}>
          <Input
            placeholder="Title"
            style={{
              margin: "4px 3px",
              minWidth: "132px",
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#F2F3F5",
            }}
            bordered={false}
            allowClear
          />
          <CloseOutlined
            style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginLeft: "4px" }}
            onClick={() => handleRemoveColumn("Some Key")}
          />
        </Space.Compact>
      </Form.Item>
    </th>
  );
}
```

How can i remove a column by clicking on the Close button in each header cell? I can't seem to figure a way to pass the column key into each header cell.

Comment: If you pass a variable into the cell function, the resulting object gives you a little info about the cell. Sadly, the key isnt in this object, but it looks like the cell title is, so you may be able to use that to lookup the columns by title. Not ideal as uniqueness isnt guaranteed, but depending on your solution, may be ok.

Table > components > header > cell: (someVar) => (...your cell code here...)

Comment: Hey, it worked. Thanks a lot for your response. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table:

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    components={{
      header: {
        cell: (cell: any) => (
          <EditableCell
            cellInfo={cell}
            handleRemoveColumn={handleRemoveColumn}
          />
        ),
        row: EditableRow,
      },
    }}
    dataSource={datasource}
    tableLayout="fixed"
    style={{ flex: "auto", maxWidth: "96.3%" }}
    scroll={{ x: "auto" }}
    bordered
    pagination={false}
  />
```

The Cell:

```
<th
  style={{ padding: "0px 6px 0px 0px" }}
  // onClick={() => console.log("Remove?")}
>
  <Form.Item style={{ margin: "4px" }}>
    <Space.Compact block={true}>
      <Input
        placeholder="Title"
        style={{
          margin: "4px 3px",
          minWidth: "132px",
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#F2F3F5",
        }}
        bordered={false}
        allowClear
      />
      <CloseOutlined
        style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginLeft: "4px" }}
        onClick={() => handleRemoveColumn(cellInfo.title)}
      />
    </Space.Compact>
  </Form.Item>
</th>
```

The column:

```
[{
  dataIndex: "newColumn1", // Unique identifier for the column
  key: "newColumn1",
  onHeaderCell: () => {
    return {
      title: "newColumn1",
    };
  },
},]
```

The title prop can be added using 'onHeaderCell'. Docs about 'onHeaderCell' -> [ColumnProp['onHeaderCell']](https://ant.design/components/table#column)

Comment: remember to generate unique keys. Or else there might be a chance for multiple columns to be deleted when clicking on only 1 close button.